# no reputation being generated

Tags: support

I've had a couple of Q & As on the meta site that not been converted into CWs yet no rep has been given. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

That is the way it is supposed to be. Excepting meta.stackoverflow.com metas draw their rep from the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, reputations are generated, but it is just hidden.

https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/61/cbrulak?tab=reputation